# No effect when I set 'max_usb_current' in /boot/config.txt on a Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, usb-power

I want recharge my iPhone from my Pi 3 Model B's USB port.

In `/boot/config.txt`, I have set

```
max_usb_current=1
```

This does not seem to have an effect any more. Why is this?

Answer (score 4):

The Pi3 is set to supply 1.2A and is not adjustable.

See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations) for more detail.

Whether this will charge the phone, depends on the phone. Many phones have proprietary protocols to set charge rate.